# Amazon EC2 I'm able to login without key and without password with ubuntu user, why?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, ssh-keys

I've created an EC2 instance with ubuntu. During instance creation I generated key pair but didn't specify any password for the key pair.

It's weird that I'm able to login to server with ubuntu username without specifying key pair or password.

Can anyone point me out what did I miss and how to do it properly during EC2 instance creation?

After all the whole purpose of creating key pair during instance creation was to prevent anyone logging in without key pair. May be I missed something?

Comment: Do `ssh -vvv ubuntu@<instance>` and post the output (removing anything sensitive).

Comment: I'm on windows box, used FileZilla, entered Elastic IP of instance, port 22 user ubuntu and hit connect, bingo I was in without password. I didn't specify any key file in FileZilla. I'm not accessing it via ssh so ssh-agent stuff doesn't apply here. It happened with 2 instances I created on Amazon in similar fashion.

Comment: @Jack FileZilla is using SFTP on port 22, which is still using SSH, so an ssh-agent does absolutely apply here. If you have something like Pageant running then FileZilla will try to use any keys loaded into that agent.

Comment: That's right Pageant was running, key was loaded in Pageant. I wasn't aware that FileZilla accepts keys loaded in Pageant. I wasn't able to check  connection anymore as I had to delete EC2 instance which become unreachable after instant restart. Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 4):

Most probably you have the key stored in your `ssh-agent` with your passphrase and it is offered automatically. The verbose log as mentioned in the comments (`ssh -vvv ubuntu@<instance>`) will confirm this.